# Defer a prototype function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I create class in JS

```
function UnitTable(options){
  this.name = options.name;
}

UnitTable.prototype = {
  query : function(){
    $.post('php.php', { func : "get" }, function(data){
       if (data) this.data = data;
    });
    return this;
  },

  append : function(){
     $('#result').append(this.data);
  }
}

var unitTable = new UnitTable(options).query().append();
```

The issue is that the AJAX call being async will not finish before the append is called.

I have tried using $.Deferred() but cannot seem to return it properly (such as reutrn deferred.promise()) and continue the chained events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it like that, but you can set a promise value in `query`, and handle the callback in `append`:

```
UnitTable.prototype = {
  query: function() {
    this.queryPromise = $.post('php.php', {func: "get"});
    return this;
  },
  append: function() {
    this.queryPromise.done(function(data) {
      $('#result').append(data);
    });
    return this;
  }
};

new UnitTable(options).query().append();
```

Comment: I suppose it is ok, but you have to be aware of control flow; that line won't run before the next line in the code.

Comment: No, this is not a good way to proceed. If a reference to the instance of `UnitTable(options)` was kept, then further calls to its `query()` method could be made *before* earlier requests were settled. But with only one `this.queryPromise`, all requests would have to "share" it. The last request to be settled would win the battle, with no guarantee which request that would be - first, last or something in between. On the assumption that the last request should be the guaranteed victor then to be safe, you need to make sure that `query()`, aborts any previous request before initiatig a new one.

Comment: @Roamer-1888, yes that's a good point. You could also keep track of the promises in a closure, and then chain them, or if the order doesn't matter, then use `$.when`.

Comment: Yes, though it depends on the OP's usage case. Progressively building a `.then()` chain is certainly a way to preserve order.

Comment: But then there would be another consideration. How to handle multiple instances of `UnitTable`. It may be better to write `UnitTable` as a singleton rather than a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with plain promises like [@elclanrs suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26187510); an alternative that would allow you to keep most of your structure above is to use a list of callbacks. jQuery provides a nice way of managing that for you with [callbacks](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.callbacks/):

```
function UnitTable(options){
  this.name = options.name;
  this._appendCallbacks = $.Callbacks("once memory");
}

UnitTable.prototype = {
  query : function(){
    $.post('php.php', { func : "get" }, function(data){
       if (data) this.data = data;
       this._appendCallbacks.fire();
    });
    return this;
  },

  append : function(){
     this._appendCallbacks.add(
       $.proxy(function() { $('#result').append(this.data); }, this)
     );
  }
}

var unitTable = new UnitTable(options).query().append();
```